# не могу достать из object данные C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleSnake
{
    public class Params
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        public Params(int x,int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public int GetX()
        {
            return this.x;
        }

        public int GetY()
        {
            return this.y;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void timerexec(object tets)
        {
            int X = tets.GetX(); //<-Not Work
            int Y = tets.GetY(); //<-Not Work

            Console.Clear();

            for (int f = 0; Y > f; f++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; X > i; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("0");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(tets.);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimerCallback tc = new TimerCallback(timerexec);
            Params pa = new Params(50, 20);
            Timer ti = new Timer(tc,pa,0,1000);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Рано или поздно вы нарвётесь на проблему с таймером: он перестанет работать, потому что его удалит сборщик мусора. Сейчас таймер - локальная переменная. Нужно его сделать полем класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static void timerexec(object tets)
    {
        Params p = tets as Params;
        if (p != null) {
            int X = p.GetX(); //<- Work
            int Y = p.GetY(); //<- Work
```

Comment: Это что-то схоже с привидением типов?

Comment: @СырныйПирог Да.

Comment: Можно более конкретно или где я могу об этом прочитать?

Comment: @СырныйПирог Об этом можно прочитать в MSDN.